Clickhouse Refreshable materialized views MV REFRESH
Tryin to understand how to make mv_test_data_mv MV Refreshable every 1 minute. Didn't find any examples with SummingMergeTree table :( Any idea?
Here is an example of tables with usual Materialized view.
CREATE TABLE guardicore.mv_test_data_tmp
(
    `id` UUID,
    `some_id` UUID,
    `count` UInt32,
    `aggr_id` FixedString(64),
    `start_time` DateTime64(6)
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toDate(start_time)
ORDER BY start_time
TTL toDateTime(start_time) + toIntervalHour(1);

CREATE TABLE guardicore.mv_test_data
(
    `id` UUID,
    `some_id` UUID,
    `count` Nullable(UInt32),
    `aggr_id` FixedString(64),
    `start_15m` DateTime
)
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree
PARTITION BY toDate(start_15m)
ORDER BY (aggr_id, start_15m);


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW guardicore.mv_test_data_mv TO guardicore.mv_test_data
(
    `aggr_id` FixedString(64),
    `start_time` DateTime,
    `count` Nullable(UInt64),
    `some_id` UUID,
    `id` UUID,
) AS
SELECT
    aggr_id,
    anyLast(id) AS id,
    anyLast(some_id) AS some_id,
    toStartOfFifteenMinutes(start_time) AS start_15m,
    sum(count) AS count,
FROM guardicore.mv_test_data_tmp
GROUP BY
    aggr_id,
    start_15m
ORDER BY
    aggr_id,
    start_15m


you are use non refreshable MV when use CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
look to https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/view#refreshable-materialized-view for details
your current implementation is a just AFTER INSERT trigger for new data which inserted into guardicore.mv_test_data_tmp

Yes, but when i am doing CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW REFRESH EVERY 1 MINUTE guardicore.mv_test_data_mv TO guardicore.mv_test_data (     aggr_id FixedString(64),     start_time DateTime,     count Nullable(UInt64),     some_id UUID,     id UUID, ) AS SELECT     aggr_id,     anyLast(id) AS id,     anyLast(some_id) AS some_id,     toStartOfFifteenMinutes(start_time) AS start_15m,     sum(count) AS count, FROM guardicore.mv_test_data_tmp GROUP BY     aggr_id,     start_15m ORDER BY     aggr_id,     start_15m it creates MV in CH, but not doing any refreshes, MV and target empty

maybe because of this - not compatible with Replicated database or table engines

MVs in ClickHouse are updated upon data insertions into the underlying source table. They do not support a refresh operation based on time intervals.
If you need to refreshing a MV every minute, you could use a scheduled task outside of ClickHouse to periodically insert new date into the source table, guardicore.mv_test_data_tmp. This would trigger the MV to update.

I think they added REFRESH support at the beginning of 2024.
